# Dynamic area painting

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, paint

I have such drawing (It can be in a vector format):

[alt text http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/2791/dom1.gif](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/2791/dom1.gif)

It is necessary for me to place it on a site and dynamically to paint it. The user chooses colour (of walls and roof)and both the wall and a roof on a picture change the colour (according to a choice of the user).

[alt text http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/3946/domq.gif](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/3946/domq.gif)

The set of colours is not limited.

What technology to use for the decision of this problem (I think that it should be client-side technology)?

Variants: pure css, canvas + javascript, jQuery, ...

Restriction: we do not use flash technology.

Comment: I would suggest looking over the RaphaelJS package: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for the advice, it is a very good library. I decided to use it to solve my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose the library Raphael.

I save the picture in the format `svg` and with the tool http://onlypaths.com/aaopblog/2009/11/7/ convert `svg` to `Raphael format` (record, understandable for Raphael).

Next - required fields fill with the color by a super-library Raphael.

---

Another translation tool from `svg` a format understandable for Raphael -
http://bkp.ee/atirip/

Answer (score 0):

for firefox and chrome, you have the `canvas` element available (although i don't believe 3d contexts are implemented, if that matters). those 2 also support `svg`. internet explorer has `vml` available, if you can deal with changing your doctype and maybe jumping through some other hoops. you can use javascript to plot all the points and whatnot. additionally, you can write  `vml` inline with the page.